# How to change the div when i hover a li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My intention**

When i `hover` over a `li` on `#featuredThumbs li` I want to swap the `div` under `#productText`

How can I accomplish this? I want to add a active state to both the `li` and `div`. I also want it to automatically start when the page loads.

[Here is my jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/breezy/DKTWz/)

**JS**

```
 $("#featuredThumbs li").hover( function() {
          $(".active").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum!</h2>
  <div id="featuredProducts">
    <div id="productText">
      <div id="autoText" class="products">
        <h3>Auto Insurance</h3>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea</p>
      </div>
      <!-- eo : products -->
      <div id="homeText" class="products">
        <h3>Auto Insurance</h3>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea</p>
      </div>
      <!-- eo : products -->
      <div id="commercialText" class="products">
        <h3>Auto Insurance</h3>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea</p>
      </div>
      <!-- eo : products -->
      <div id="lifeText" class="products">
        <h3>Auto Insurance</h3>
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea</p>
      </div>
      <!-- eo : products -->

    </div>
    <!-- eo: productText -->
    <ul id="featuredThumbs">
      <li id="autoProd"></li>
      <li id="homeProd"></li>
      <li id="commercialProd"></li>
      <li id="lifeProd"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- eo : featuredProducts -->

</div>
​
```

Comment: the `li` are suppose to have images but i could not upload them so i added a background color to them @AntonBaksheiev. by swap i mean switch the div to the next one @adrian.

Comment: don't mean to demand @Alexander just need help. sorry! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this may help you:

CSS:

```
.products { display:none; }
.products.active { display:block; }
```

JS:

```
$("#featuredThumbs li").hover( function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    var textid = this.id.replace("Prod", "Text");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#" + textid).addClass("active");
});​
```

This works as long as the id of the li elements ends in 'Prod' and the matching text ends in 'Text'. I also added the class `active` to the first div.

http://jsfiddle.net/KfEuL/

Comment: This definitely does the job!

Comment: how could i get this to start automatically?

Comment: Like that: `$(document).ready(function() { /* hover code goes here */ });`

Comment: i mean like switch over to the next `div` automatically when the dom loads and also when i hover over the `li`

Comment: What would be the 'next' div? Sorry, I don't think I get your question. It's probably what I did here http://jsfiddle.net/KfEuL/1/
I add the 'active' style manually when the page loads. I also defined an 'active' style for the `li` so it will look the same as `#featuredThumbs li:hover` style.

Comment: i appreciate your help. what i want it to do is when the page loads i want it to 'auto cycle' through the divs and on `hover`. im not sure if i have to put it through a set interval ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
     $("#featuredThumbs li").hover( 
     function(){
           $(this).addClass("active");
           $(this).append($('#'+$(this).attr('id').replace('Prod','Text')).html());
         },
     function(){
           $(".active").removeClass("active");
           $(this).html("");
        }
     );​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/abaksheyev/b6seS/1/)

Comment: this adds the text inside the `li` which is not what i want it to do. but thanks. upvote for the attempt/help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
// activate first item
$("#productText .products:first").show().siblings().hide(); 
$("#featuredThumbs li:first").addClass("active");

// set hover handler
$("#featuredThumbs li").hover( function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // find div id based on li id
    var liId = $(this).attr('id');
    var liIdParts =  liId.split("-");
    var divId = liIdParts[0] + "Text";

    $("#" + divId)
        .addClass("active")
        .show()
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active")
        .hide();    
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DKTWz/2/)

**UPDATE: with auto switching**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DKTWz/3/)

```
var nextLi;
var autoSwitch = setInterval(function(){
    var firstLi = $("#featuredThumbs li:first");

    if(nextLi == undefined){
        nextLi = firstLi;
    }else{
        nextLi = nextLi.next("li");
        nextLi = (nextLi.length == 0) ? firstLi : nextLi;
    }  
    switchToDivForLi(nextLi);    
}, 3000);

$("#productText .products:first").show().siblings().hide(); 
$("#featuredThumbs li:first").addClass("active");

$("#featuredThumbs li").hover( function() {
    switchToDivForLi($(this));

    if(autoSwitch != undefined){
        clearInterval(autoSwitch);  
    }        
});

function switchToDivForLi(liElement){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
        liElement.addClass("active");

        var liId = liElement.attr('id');
        $("#" + liId.replace("Prod", "Text"))
            .addClass("active")
            .show()
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("active")
            .hide(); 
}
```

Comment: this has too many variables and i was looking for something smaller and minimal upvote for the help!

Comment: how can i get it to start on page load and on hover?

Comment: It does just that I think. Check th demo. If not you need to explain a bit better what you want to happen.

Comment: first. i appreciate your help. i want it to cycle through automatically and when you manually `hover` over the `li`s. i want it do both

Comment: You can move the functionality of the hover handler to a separate function that takes an li element as an argument. Then on hover you provide $(this) as the argument. Next create an interval function that triggers the function with the first li element as the argument. Keep track of the current li and cycle through them one by one in the interval function.

Comment: not exactly sure how to do this. do you know of any references @JeroenMoons ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a new example which does what I explained. Automatic switching, it stops once the user hovers on something himself.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(function() {
    $("#featuredThumbs li").hover( function() {
          $(".active").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $('.products').hide();
          $('#' + this.id.replace('Prod','Text')).show()
    });
});​​
```

Don't forget to change the titles for the product divs so you can tell them apart (right now they all say "Auto Insurance"). I also added this to the css:

```
.products { display: none; }
```

---

To make it cycle automatically, this is the full code:

```
var intervalLen = 1000; //milliseconds 
$(function() {
    $("#featuredThumbs li").mouseover( function() {
          $(".active").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $('.products').hide();
          $('#' + this.id.replace('Prod','Text')).show();

          clearInterval(interval);
    });

    $("#featuredThumbs li").mouseout(function() {
        interval = setInterval(showNext,intervalLen);
    });
});

function showNext() {
    var visible = $('div', $('#productText')).not(':hidden');
    var next = visible.next('.products'); 
    if(next.length == 0) {
        next = $('div:first-child', $('#productText'));
    }
    visible.hide();
    next.show();
}

var interval;
​$(function() {
    interval = setInterval(showNext,intervalLen);
});
```

And the extra line of CSS changes to:

```
.products:not(:first-child) { display: none; }
```

It will not cycle when the user hovers over one item because the onmouseover event stops the interval and the onmouseout restarts it. You can change the speed of the cycle by changing `intervalLen`

Comment: yes but i also need it to start automatically as soon as the dom loads and not just on hover

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
document.getElementById('featuredThumbs').onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('productText').innerHTML = 'swap';
}
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't see your code somehow. Am new to StackOverflow.